# onClick is always returning 25

Tags: html, reactjs, for-loop

I'm using reactjs.

I have a series of divs that are created that represent a employee's availability. When clicked, they will display the number. However, they all alert the number 25 instead of their number.

```
for (
      var i = state.availability[day][0];
      i <= state.availability[day][1];
      i++
    ) {
      tempdaySlot.push(
        <div
          key={"ena:" + TimeConverter(i)}
          style={LocalStyles.daySlot}
          onClick={() => alert(i)}
        >
          {TimeConverter(i)}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

*state.availability* is a two dimensional array that holds a number between 1-24 that represents someone's availability (ex [9-17])

*TimeConverter* is a function that converts a 24 hour type number to the usual 12 hour format (17 = "5 pm")

*tempdaySlot* is just a temporary array before I put it into a state variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `let i` instead of `var i`. var hoists variable to the parent scope, let creates block scope.

Answer (score 1):

Tl;dr declare `i` using `let`, not `var`

The `var` keyword creates variables with function scope. However, when you create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (like your `onClick` function), the lexical environment is captured by reference. When you call that `onClick` function later, it gets the *current* value of `i` (which is 25, since that's where the loop stopped), not the value of `i` when you created the function.

The `let` keyword creates `i` with traditional scoping, so in effect a new `i` is created on each iteration of the loop which solves this problem.

See [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) for more.

Comment: That worked! Thank you for the expanded explanation of why I was getting 25

Answer (score 1):

this is a hoisting issue, because you defined the `i` using `var` it will be hoisted to the top of the function body so the last value which is `25` will be the only thing stored in that variable and since the variable isn't destroyed because it's hoisted it will only show the latest value.

just use `let` instead of `var` its a good practice to use `let` and `const` instead of `var` now so try getting used it, it will save you a lot of headaches.